# policy to see cloudwatch metric of EC2 and EBS only from UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cloudwatch:namespace": 
                    [
                     "AWS/EC2/Per-Instance Metrics",
                     "EBS"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created above policy but it is not working, its showing me error if I am using above condition.
Can anyone please help how to restrict console level permission just fo EBS and EC2 metrics.

Comment: What error? Why its not working? Can you provide any debugging info?

Comment: When I used above policy with condition, its showing me listmetrics not allowed , but when I removed condition , its showing me all metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information presented in [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon CloudWatch - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncloudwatch.html), the `ListMetrics`, `GetMetricData` and `GetMetricStatistics` commands do not accept any Condition keys.

Therefore, it would not be possible to restrict the data returned by these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use ForAllValues as below. Also do check your namespace names. They are not correct namespace names. It should be AWS/EC2. Sorry for formatting issue, just typing this on phone.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "cloudwatch:namespace": 
                    [
                     "AWS/EC2",
                     "AWS/EBS"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: For all values, it will show all metrics not EBS or EC2 only

Comment: Huh? Are you sure? Read this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html

Edited my answer now that I am on my laptop for better formatting. You can also use ForAnyValue. But make sure you add the write namespace names.

Comment: To further explain, the key "cloudwatch:namespace" can take a value of String, not List type if you use StringEquals. If you want to match multiple values, you use ForAllValues or ForAnyValue along with StringEquals. Hope that clears it.

Comment: I used ForAnyValue also , but it will show me same error of list metrics , also I used AWS/EC2 inplace of above

Comment: Ahh John's answer is right. These actions are not supported for Condition. Missed to check the same.